# What are the open source options to extract pdf pages as pngs?

Tags: .net, pdf, open-source, png

I would like to extract pdf pages as png files to be manipulated in a image viewing module that I am writing. I originally used the ConvertPDF wrapper for ghostscript but it seems to be having trouble with multipage pdfs.

Update: It seemed like all roads ended up back at GS so I stuck with [ConvertPDF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GhostScriptUseWithCSharp.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) for that purpose, again a Ghostscript wrapper in the case of PDFs.

Either the command line can be used, or one of the wrapper libraries.

An example command line could be.

```
convert -density 300 mydocument.pdf[2] page-3.png
```

(Important to state image density (DPI) on PDF reads)

Comment: Note, if you end up using the [ImageMagick.Net wrapper](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/), then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916555/converting-pdf-to-images-using-imagemagick-net-how-to-set-the-dpi) might be of use regarding density.