# Convert Rtf, Excel, Pdf, or Html file formats to image

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm working on a feature for a .NET 4 WPF/WCF/EF 4/SQL 2008 application that supports adding/editing Rtf or Excel content. We're using 3rd party components from Telerik and GrapeCity to support Rtf and Excel editing inside our product.

Among other pertinent fields, the "Entry" entity is simple and includes an `RtfContent varchar(max)`, `ExcelContent varbinary(max)`, and `IsRtf (bit)`. IsRtf indicates if the Entry uses Rtf (true) or Excel (false). They are mutually exclusive.

Using the 3rd party controls, I can "export" the Rtf and Excel data as Pdf, Html, or each as Rtf and Xlsx.

We're wanting to include the Rtf or Excel content into a report, and we're using Data Dynamics Reporting package. I'm stumped on how or even if we can accommodate this request since Data Dynamics doesn't offer support for Rtf, Excel, Html, or Pdf. They do however, offer support for Tiff (and some other image formats).

I'm not sure if this would be a trivial conversion, but it may be the only way to include this content in a Data Dynamics Report.

Is it possible to convert any of those formats to a Tiff image? Or would it be possible to somehow "capture" the content of one of the 3rd party controls as a Tiff?

I can't say that I like the thought of performing conversions like this, but I'm running out of ideas.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question addresses converting PDF to different images in C# and would probably work for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711942/convert-pdf-file-to-jpg-asp-net

Comment: Thanks for the response. ImageMagick for .NET looks like it will work, but it's a little more than I wanted to get into for this particular application. I was hoping to do an in-memory conversion, but I don't know if that's possible using this approach. This sample helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916555/converting-pdf-to-images-using-imagemagick-net-how-to-set-the-dpi

Comment: This link is now broken.