# Set image resolution

Tags: c#, imagemagick, resolution

I have array of image bytes and I would like to set resolution. Original image can be JPEG, PNG, BMP. Output - PNG. I am using ImageMagic to convert image and do some manipulations.

```
        using (var image = this.Convert(originalImage, height, width))
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
                image.Quality = 90;
                image.Write(stream, MagickFormat.Png);
                return stream.GetBuffer();
        }
```

I tryed to modify `image.GetExifProfile`, but has no success (at least for PNG images).

I can't use any comandline tool (like ImageMagic or ExifTool) here.

There are 3 exiff tags I need to modify

- XResolution
- YResolution
- ResolutionUnit

I can successfully achieve this with bitmap, but it also resource overhead (need to create MemoryStream ...).

I have found some [Pdf specification](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf), but it will consume time to make it all work.

Does any can point me to right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916555/converting-pdf-to-images-using-imagemagick-net-how-to-set-the-dpi)

Comment: @TaW, thanks! I have missed Density property.