# How do I get a std::exception error description when calling a C++ dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, exception

I have a C# application which calls a function in a C++ dll. This function can throw various exceptions which inherits `std::exception`. I currently catch these exceptions like this:

```
try
{
    //Call to C++ dll
}
catch (System.Exception exception)
{
    //Some error handling code
}
```

My first question is will this code catch all `std::exception`? My second question is how can I retrieve the `std::exception::what` string, if I examine `exception.Message` I only get "External component has thrown an exception".

**EDIT:** The function in question is in a non managed C++ dll, and imported like this in the C# class:

```
[DllImport("SomeDLL.dll")]
public extern static void SomeFunction();
```

Comment: There is a ToString method returns a string representation of the current exception. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception_members.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150544/can-you-catch-a-native-exception-in-c-code/150596#150596

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go would be to handle the exception in C++, and save the error message somewhere. Then, in C# you can check if there was an error message saved, and if it was you can retrieve it.

C++:

```
try
{
    //do some processing
}
catch(std::exception& ex)
{
    // errorMessage can be a std::string
    errorMessage = ex.what();
}
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("SomeDLL.dll")]
public extern static void SomeFunction();
[DllImport("SomeDLL.dll")]
public extern static string GetError();

SomeFunction();
string Error = GetError();
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Error)==true)
{
    //The processing was successfull
}
else
{
    //The processing was unsuccessful
    MessageBox.Show(Error);
}
```

Comment: And what if it is a third party code I have no possibility to modify it?

Comment: Link against the library in your own C++ wrapper library.

Comment: This work as well the other way around: catching c# exception from c++ native code. You need to activate SEH exception to work correctly. In the c# wrapper, I save the ex->Message to char * member (using Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi) and return with get method. In c++ in "catch(...)" block I read the exception by the get method and throw a std::exception with that message.

Answer (score 0):

Call how? The CLR doesn't really "get" C++ exception handling. If you call the C++ code through COM, add a layer that catches the std::exception and wrap it with a HRESULT/IErrorInfo. If you call it through managed C++, add a layer that wraps it in a managed System.Exception etc.

Comment: The same principle applies to PInvoke. It's easier to find some other protocol for error reporting. Using the return values, output parameters and/or Windows' SetLastError function for example.