# C++/CLI double pointer typecasting to ref IntPtr for C# access

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, c++-cli, marshalling

I am writing a wrapper around C DLL in C++/CLI so that it can be accessed in C# through a managed assembly. Using direct P/Invoke to access C functions via C# is not possible because C DLL raises exceptions which cannot be correctly caught using P/Invoke (exception message is lost when moving across C/C# boundary). So the idea is to create a managed CLI DLL which internally calls C DLL and wraps the exception to Exception class of CLI.

So the C DLL function has this declaration.

```
void InitDB(void **handle);
```

The C# app would required following declaration

```
void InitDB_cs(ref IntPtr handle);
```

To accomplish this I created C++/CLI function with following declaration

```
void InitDB_clr(IntPtr %handle);
```

However, I am unable to typecast ref InPtr into C function. I tried using following code but seems can't get the typecasting right.

```
void InitDB_clr(IntPtr %handle)
{
pin_ptr<IntPtr> ptr = handle.ToPointer();
InitDB(&ptr);
}
```

Error message for above code

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'cli::pin_ptr<Type>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Type=System::IntPtr
1>        ]
1>        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>error C2664: 'InitDB' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::pin_ptr<Type> *' to 'void **'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Type=System::IntPtr
1>        ]
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: Sorry typing error. Its InitDB (C DLL function). Thanks for bringing to my notice.

Comment: No prob. I don't know CLI, but what's the error? Does it help if you cast `&ptr` to `void**`?

Comment: I tried that but it gives me typecasting error similar to above.

Comment: Why do you declare function `InitDB_clr()` with the parameter `handle` when you never use it?

Comment: I know this is not your question, but are you sure the C++/CLI wrapper will be able to handle the exceptions? No DLL should let exceptions escape.

Comment: @Rudy: The reason for switching to C++/CLI instead of directly using P/Invoke in C# is the issue I asked on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753292/handling-user-defined-exceptions-from-c-dll-net-pinvoke-marshalling . Now in the question i mentioned an MSDN link which tells how to wrap native C++ exceptions to CLI compatible exceptions. That is my requirement and I am trying to acheive that since the code solves the issue at hand.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Good luck. I assume you have no control over the source of the DLL? That would make things a lot easier, I guess.

Comment: I cannot change the source code of DLL, its a part of the bigger application and I am not allowed to make changes as it will break other modules. But since CLI DLL will be used in sync with WPF app, so I can create custom APIs for C DLL.

Comment: How are you throwing exception in C? Are you using some type of library, or are you using Windows' SEH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an `out` parameter, not really `ref`, correct?

Try

```
void InitDB_clr(IntPtr% handle)
{
    void* ptr /* = handle.ToPointer() */;
    InitDB(&ptr);
    handle = IntPtr(ptr);
}
```

Uncomment the initializer if it needs to be in/out.

Comment: With the code above i get the following error when I compile in C++/CLI project: : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'System::IntPtr ^' to 'System::IntPtr'

Comment: @KSingh : Don't use `gcnew`. By the way, this was already answered on the MSDN forums where [you asked the same question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/fdb13eb5-f6bd-4710-aadd-ebc898992bf9).

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks.. I cross posted on both stackoverflow and MSDN forums. And appreciate your help, it works now :)

Comment: Ugh, yeah, I was thinking of C# where it's required to use `new` with value types.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use C# in an unsafe context and use

```
unsafe void InitDB_cs(IntPtr** handle);
```

Comment: I dont want to have pointers/unsafe code in C#. That is one of the reason for having C++/CLI managed which will have all the functions for C# and internally interacts with C DLL.