# How to import a C++ function with int** and double** parameters

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport, intptr

I am trying to import a C++ function in my C# code.

This function is defined as:

```
int SetPointers(int* ID, int* BufferID, int** Pointer, double** Time, int NumberOfPointers);
```

with ID an array of int,
BufferId an array of int,
Pointer an array of int,
Time an array of double, and
NumberOfPointers an int.

I have tried to use IntPtr without success.

Here is the latest code I tried:

```
[DllImport("open.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public unsafe static extern int SetPointers(int* ID, int* BufferID, ref IntPtr Pointer, ref IntPtr Time, int NumberOfPointers);
public unsafe int _SetPointers(int[] ID, int[] BufferID, ref int[] Pointer, ref double[] Time, int NumberOfPointers)
{
    IntPtr fQueue = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr fTime = IntPtr.Zero;
    int breturn = -1;
    fixed (int* fId = ID)
    fixed (int* fBufferID = BufferID)
    fQueue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)) * Pointer.Length);
    fTime = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(double)) * Timestamp.Length);
    breturn = SetPointers(fId, fBufferID, ref fQueue, ref fTime, NumberOfPointers);
    return breturn;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What does `malloc` have to do with the question?

Comment: You need to show, how this function is used in unmanaged code. Or show the function code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant marshal

Comment: I can't modify that code, and it is very complex. Basically, ID, BufferId and NumberOfPointers are only read by the function and Pointer and Time are like returned values. Does this help?

Comment: I dont think you are doing the right thing. Double referencing is probably an out parameter - Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810419/c-cli-double-pointer-typecasting-to-ref-intptr-for-c-sharp-access

Comment: What happens when the 'fixed' statement is not "scoped" with `{}` (like it is in all examples)? Does it actually work as intended in this case?

Comment: The scope of 'fixed' is [limited to single lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663394/using-fixed-for-a-pointer-statement/8664063#8664063) (in this case). What consequence does this have? For instance, will `fBufferID` be protected in `breturn = SetPointers(fId, fBufferID, ref fQueue, ref fTime, NumberOfPointers);`?

Comment: From *[Nested 'fixed' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782992/)*: *"After the code in the statement is executed, any pinned variables are unpinned and subject to garbage collection. Therefore, do not point to those variables outside the 'fixed' statement."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First all, you might want to use IntPtr for your parameters rather than int[].

After this, I haven't tried it but to marshal pointers on pointers a "ref IntPtr" or "out IntPtr" would work.

```
public unsafe int _SetPointers(IntPtr ID, IntPtr BufferID, ref IntPtr Pointer, ref IntPtr Time, int NumberOfPointers);
```

Also have a look to this other question: *[How do I marshall a pointer to a pointer of an array of structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131676/how-do-i-marshall-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-of-an-array-of-structures)*

Comment: First two parameters are fine as arrays