# Can't catch native exception in managed code

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a mixed .NET and native code console application. The application process is terminated due to Visual C RunTime Library fatal error. Even though I am using the following, the managed code doesn’t catch the native exception:

1. Try/catch block
2. `AppDomain.UnHandledExption += ...`
3. Marking the `RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)` in the AssmblyInfo file.

What else can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you catch a native exception in C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150544/can-you-catch-a-native-exception-in-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 21):

Native exceptions have changed in .NET 4 so that they can not be catched with a standard catch block.  You specifically have to mark the function where the exception is being thrown as `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` to be able to catch it.

More here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx

Watch out for the notes in that article, like if you'd like to catch them normally rather than follow their advice of executing the finally block and exiting, add `legacyCorruptedState­­ExceptionsPolicy=true` into your config file.

Answer (score -2):

Catch without () will catch non-CLS compliant exceptions including native exceptions.

```
try
{

}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: I made my comment based on this FxCop rule..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/bb264489.aspx
Sorry it didn't work..