# Catching native code exceptions in .NET

Tags: c#, c++, exception, ffmpeg, native-code

I'm currently working with ffmpeg with a proprietary wrapper and I need to catch native code exceptions that sometimes occur during transcoding procedures etc.

I already read those questions/answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517199/cant-catch-native-exception-in-managed-code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150544/can-you-catch-a-native-exception-in-c-sharp-code

However, they were not really helpful as the exceptions occur not during a function I call, but in a completely different thread that runs side-by-side in the ffmpeg library and were thrown by additional components such as DirectX. This is somehow a real issue as the exceptions tear down my whole application!

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This cannot be done directly.
Handle the exception in native code and return properdata from native code when exception occurs. In managed code you can know if any exception occurred by checking the returned value/data.

Comment: @Narendra The exception occurs probably in DirectX, as I mentioned in the question, which is a proprietary component. There is no way I can alter any of its methods to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exceptions thrown from other threads using these 2 events:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
// Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

You might also need to set the following in your App.config file:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" />
  </runtime>
...
```

If you can't get it to work with managed code, the code below will catch everything in native (c++) code (not sure if you can PInvoke it):

```
//Sets the handler for a pure virtual function call. 
_set_purecall_handler( &MyPureVirtualCallHandler );

// Sets the handler function to be called when invalid parameters are passed to C runtime functions
_set_invalid_parameter_handler( &MyInvalidParameterHandler );

//Register an unhandled exception filter
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(&UnhandExceptionFilter);
```