# Exception cannot be caught

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, exception

I have a WinForms application which dynamically loads an assembly generated by MatLab (3rd Party). Currently, I encountered the problem that an error (maybe exception) somewhere in the MatLab code structure, cannot be caught on C# side. And by this, the whole application goes down...

What I tried is:

- Try/Catch Block (even with no exception type, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/150675/3809520)
- HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10517244/3809520)

Is there anything that I could do more?

Thanks!

Edit:
Application is using .NET 4.5 Framework

Edit2:
Tried `Application.ThreadException` event together with `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)` and  `AppDomain.UnhandledExceptions` event as proposed in comment - both events not triggered.

Edit3:
I will try to nail it down to a minimal example, the questions was intended to be more generic, like: what else can be done on my code side to catch exceptions

Comment: Indeed there are exceptions you can´t catch, because there simply is no meaningful way of handling them at all. Best example here is a `StackOverflowException`. However, without seeing any code it´s impossible to guess what exception you may talk about.

Comment: Did you check event viewer on the machine where you are getting this exception ?  It may provide a clue.

Comment: As its winforms, you can use application.threadexception, Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode

Comment: Please describe in more detail how you're loading the assembly, and show us some of your code. Is there a reason why you're not calling the assembly through interop (native code) instead?