# catch(Exception e) is not catching exception thrown by managed dll

Tags: c#, exception

```
try
{
    value = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName; 
}       
catch (Exception e)
{
    //handle exception
}
```

I am trying to call a method from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ni.dll to locate the UPN for the user to authenticate the client. However, in the case where the user's password has been changed by an administrator, this dll is throwing an exception and I can't figure out why catch(Exception e) is not handling it. The exception is bubbling up and taking down my application.

Is there something else I need to do to catch this exception?

Comment: Unmanaged exceptions should be caught in the unmanaged DLL. You cannot expect to catch them in your managed code. You'll need to fix the DLL.

Comment: The problem is this is not my dll, this is a Microsoft dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That is a managed DLL. Where is the unmanaged DLL?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It is a managed dll that is throwing the exception.

Comment: If you cannot catch the exception, what makes you so sure that it is being thrown?

Comment: Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.DirectorySer#\46a7f51ef1a9d917598b96f7a758a459\System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ni.dll


I can also put trace statements directly before and after the call, the second one does not show up

Comment: That doesn't look like a managed exception. Do you have any more details? This sort of stuff is not much use in comments. Add the detail to the question please.

Comment: @HamptonTerry please include a full copy of the text of the error message you have logged, also please show the logging code to demonstrate that you narrowed the issue down. Lastly please add a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you are getting a error in that you should not be getting so you will need to walk us step by step in order for us to re-create the problem on our machines to diagnose what is wrong on your machine. If you can not describe how to recreate the issue the best answer you can get is "It should have worked"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you catch a native exception in C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150544/can-you-catch-a-native-exception-in-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 0):

If the `catch` block in the code in the question is not being entered, then the only conclusion is that

```
value = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.
    Current.UserPrincipalName;
```

does not throw an exception. Perhaps during the execution of this statement an exception is thrown and then caught. But the only sane conclusion that can be reached is that your catch-all handler is not catching anything is that there is nothing to be caught.