# C++ throwing error through dll to c#

Tags: c#, c++

I created C++ Dll

```
Initialize()
{
if(!_fs.isOpened())
    {
        throw ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
        _logfile << "Error ! Opening BDS.xml" << "\t" <<_arrivalTime<<endl;
        _logfile.close();
    }
}
```

and calling this function in C#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    catch (RuntimeWrappedException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error SEHException was Unhandled External Component has thrown an exception I tried C# all exception method but i did not get the correct answer. Can some One please help me?Or tell me how to throw exception from C++ Dll and Catch same Exception in C# and wait for response of C#. Like Retry, Abort, Ignore error, if Retry pressed than it again starts opening the file in Dll. how should i do this . please help me out of this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150544/can-you-catch-a-native-exception-in-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 2):

It is C++\CLI not C++ exception. In C++\CLI, do the following:

```
 throw gcnew System::Exception("It is a C++\CLI exception");
```

rather than c++ native exception