# catch native exception in dotnet core

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, interop, pinvoke

in a dotnet core application that uses pinvoke and runs on linux, when c++ throws - for example - `std::runtime_error` - we get:

```
terminate called recursively
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error*'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

even though the invocation of the externed c++ method is wrapped in a try catch block in the managed code.

how can this be caught and treated in the dotnet core managed code?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note the response https://stackoverflow.com/a/151329/613130 . You should use a `try { ... } catch { ... }` (without exception type)

Comment: Please note that my question refers to dotnet core executing on linux, not dotnet framework on windows. Is this still a duplicate?

Comment: @levhaikin Probably not...

Comment: @levhaikin Have you tried with a blanked `try... catch {}` with no type?

Comment: @xanatos thanks - I plan to try the empty try :)

Comment: by the way, why the downvote?... care to explain?..

Comment: I tried the blanked try/catch. didn't help. I can't find anything about this issue anywhere... any help?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I set-up [this Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://github.com/yaireclipse/CatchNativeExceptions) that demonstrates how native exceptions are **NOT caught whatsoever** by managed C# .NET Core code, on Linux.

As described in [the issue I opened for `dotnet/coreclr`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/19192), I've tried (m)any possible weapon(s) in the arsenal, to no avail.

The direct answer given by dotnet team was:

> We do not support exception handling interop on Unix. There is no good way to do it. The Mono project has a great write up on it here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#runtime-exception-propagation . The same reasoning applies to .NET Core.

The Mono project's solution, which is also recommended by the dotnet team, is:

> C++ exceptions will need to be mapped into an “out” parameter or a return value, so that managed code can know what error occurred, and (optionally) throw a managed exception to “propagate” the original C++ exception.

That's what we eneded up implementing and, well, it works :).